# Arduino C Multi dimensional array switching

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im stuck with a piece of my Arduino code

Basically I have a multi dimensional array in which every index will store a random letter. But after a small time (eg. 900 milliseconds) every value in the index will move up to the index above it. Ofcourse when the index reaches e.g. [9][0] it will go to the largest index like [9][9]

E.g.: myArray[9][8] contains "K" and myArray[9][7] contains "L"

The "K" in myArray[9][8] will be put in myArray[9][7] and the "L" in myArray[9][7] will go to myArray[9][6] etc. etc

But I have no clue how to do this in C...
myArray[9][8]   = myArray[9][7] obviously wouldnt work

Comment: show us your code

Comment: What's wrong with `myArray[9][8] = myArray[9][7]` ? Or better with temporary variable `tmp = myArray[9][0]; myArray[9][0] = ...[1]; ...[1] = ...[2]; ... ...[9] = tmp`

Comment: @KamilCuk I guess it moves it in the wrong direction.  It would be `myArray[9][7] = myArray[9][8]` per the description.  Generically a `for` loop with `myArray[9][i] = myArray[9][i+1]` could be used, with code to handle the wrap and a temp to store ``myArray[9][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. One would be to use a temporary variable while copying, as Kami Cuk and Fred pointed out.

Another way, which would avoid copying the values, would be to index the array using a modulo operation while reading the array.

```
myArray[9][(index + offset) % numberOfElementsInArray]
```

index and offset should both be positive integers.
numberOfElementsInArray is the number of elements in myArray[9]

To get a -1 offset with a positive integer, set offset to numberOfElementsInArray - 1

Answer (score 0):

There is not problem with assignment, but you must save the element you are writing over first.

In this example all the rewritten values are kept in the last slot of every row, this is just an example- not the only way to go, if you need to move the letters across the rows as well the idea is similar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void moveLettersInRow(char sArr[][3], int row)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char temp ;

    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {

       for(j = 2 ;j > 0;--j)
       {

           temp = sArr[i][j-1]; /*save the value to be rewritten */
           sArr[i][j-1]= sArr[i][2]; /* set the last val in its new place*/
           sArr[i][2]= temp; /* set the last elem to the latest rewritten value*/

       }
    }

}
void printArr(char arr[][3], int size)
{
    int i = 0, j= 0;
    for(i = 0; i< size; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j< 3; ++j)
        {
            printf("%c | ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
   char arr[2][3]= {{'a','b','c'},{'a','b','c'}};
   moveLettersInRow(arr, 2);
   printArr(arr, 2);
   return 0;
}
```